# How to set up and build Apache 2.4 on WINDOWS 7 Pro?

Tags: apache, websocket, load-balancing

I have a project, and need to set up and build an Apache24 server on windows, but there is almost non of information on that, can you give some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, after a lot of searching, I found an acceptable way to do it.

Software Requirements:

```
Visual Studio 2013 (I use the Community Edition)
```

Make a folder on C, call it BuildTools and install all the following programs there:

```
ActivePerl for Windows (64-bit, currently using 5.20.1.2000)
CMake for Windows (currently using 3.1.3)
GNU Awk for Windows (currently using 3.1.6-1)
GnuWin32 (any version from 2014+)
Netwide Assembler (NASM) (currently using 2.11.06)
```

Source Code Packages (I don't use ZLIB for Apache or OpenSSL, or LUA/LIBXML2/EXPAT, therefore these are not included in the process):

```
httpd-2.4.12.tar.gz
apr-1.5.1.tar.gz
apr-util.1.5.4.tar.gz
openssl-1.0.2a.tar.gz (yes it works with 1.0.2a!)
pcre-8.36.tar.gz
```

Here are the steps:

1. Extract all packages into their separate folders in your preferred source tree (e.g. C:\Development\Apache24\src)
2. Create custom build folders for Apache, PCRE, APR and APR-Util in your preferred build folder (e.g. C:\Development\Apache24\build
3. Your folder structure should resemble the below:

[image]

4. Make the following file changes so that ApacheMonitor gets built (without the Manifest error):

   C:\Development\Apache24\src\httpd-2.4.12\CMakeLists.txt
   Uncomment the section to build the ApacheMonitor utility (lines 769-775) 
   Find the following lines below, they will be in comments

   ```
   # getting duplicate manifest error with ApacheMonitor 

   ADD_EXECUTABLE(ApacheMonitor support/win32/ApacheMonitor.c support/win32/ApacheMonitor.rc)
   SET(install_targets ${install_targets} ApacheMonitor)
   SET(install_bin_pdb ${install_bin_pdb} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ApacheMonitor.pdb)
   SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(ApacheMonitor PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)
   SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(ApacheMonitor PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-DAPP_FILE -DLONG_NAME=ApacheMonitor -DBIN_NAME=ApacheMonitor.exe / ${EXTRA_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
   TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ApacheMonitor ${EXTRA_LIBS} ${HTTPD_SYSTEM_LIBS} comctl32 wtsapi32)
   ```

   Also

   C:\Development\Apache24\src\httpd-2.4.12\support\win32\ApacheMonitor.rc
   Comment out the line that includes ApacheMonitor.manifest (line 29)

   ```
   //CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST  "ApacheMonitor.manifest"
   ```

4.1 Create a set_path.bat file with the following code:

```
    SET VC_HOME=c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 13.0\VC
    call VC_HOME\vcvarsall amd64
    SET BUILD_ROOT=C:\BuildTools
    SET PATH=%PATH%;%BUILD_ROOT%\cmake\bin
    SET PATH=%PATH%;%BUILD_ROOT%\gawk\bin
    SET PATH=%PATH%;%BUILD_ROOT%\nasm
    SET PATH=%PATH%;%BUILD_ROOT%\perl\bin

You will need to run that file later in the process.
```

5. From the Start menu, launch the VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt found under Visual Studio 2013->Visual Studio Tools. Alternatively, but not recommended, from a Windows Command Prompt.

5.1 Go to GnuWin32, find his lib and the include folder,  and copy their content to the BuildTools/perl/lib folder, this should resolve some errors that came up in the process while I was doing this

5.2 This step, you can skip now, BUT, if there is an error that includes the expat.h and the expath_external.h files, Find an older version of Apache, and copy its expat_external.h to the apache24/include folder

```
Find expat.h file on this site 
https://github.com/apache/apr-util/blob/0.9.x/xml/expat/lib/expat.h

copy its content over the file, you find in apache24/include folder Find an older version of Apache (don't know exactly witch version), and copy its expat_external.h to the apache24/include folder

Find expat.h file on this site 
https://github.com/apache/apr-util/blob/0.9.x/xml/expat/lib/expat.h

copy its content over the file, you find in apache24/include folder
```

5.3. Find the set_path.bat folder from the console and run it.
    this you need to do, to be able to run the next steps

6. Navigate into the build sub-folder for PCRE, run CMAKE to generate a suitable Makefile, then compile and install

   ```
   cd /D C:\Development\Apache24\build\pcre
   cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Apache24 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DPCRE_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DPCRE_BUILD_PCRECPP=OFF -DPCRE_BUILD_PCREGREP=OFF -DPCRE_SUPPORT_PCREGREP_JIT=OFF -DPCRE_SUPPORT_UTF=ON -DPCRE_SUPPORT_UNICODE_PROPERTIES=ON -DPCRE_NEWLINE=CRLF -DINSTALL_MSVC_PDB=OFF ..\..\src\pcre-8.36
   nmake
   nmake install
   ```
7. Navigate into the source sub-folder for OpenSSL, configure the build environment for compiling with NASM, then compile and install

   ```
    cd /D C:\Development\Apache24\src\openssl-1.0.2a
    perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\Apache24 --openssldir=C:\Apache24\conf enable-camellia no-idea no-mdc2 no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-zlib
    ms\do_win64a.bat
    nmake /f ms\ntdll.mak
    nmake /f ms\ntdll.mak install
   ```
8. Navigate into the build sub-folder for APR, run CMAKE to generate a suitable Makefile, then compile and install

   ```
   cd /D C:\Development\Apache24\build\apr
   cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Apache24 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DMIN_WINDOWS_VER=0x0600 -DAPR_HAVE_IPV6=ON -DAPR_INSTALL_PRIVATE_H=ON -DAPR_BUILD_TESTAPR=OFF -DINSTALL_PDB=OFF ..\..\src\apr-1.5.1
   nmake
   nmake install
   ```
9. Navigate into the build sub-folder for APR-Util, run CMAKE to generate a suitable Makefile, then compile and install

   ```
   cd /D C:\Development\Apache24\build\apr-util
   cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Apache24 -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=C:\Apache24 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DAPU_HAVE_CRYPTO=ON -DAPR_BUILD_TESTAPR=OFF -DINSTALL_PDB=OFF ..\..\src\apr-util-1.5.4
   nmake
   nmake install
   ```
10. Navigate into the build sub-folder for Apache, run CMAKE to generate a suitable Makefile, then compile and install

    ```
    cd /D C:\Development\Apache24\build\httpd
    cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Apache24 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DENABLE_MODULES=i -DINSTALL_PDB=OFF ..\..\src\httpd-2.4.12
    nmake
    nmake install
    ```
11. Finally, confirm everything is working

    ```
    cd /D C:\Apache24\bin
    openssl version
    httpd -V
    ```

These are the steps and the problems I encountered, and I followed the steps from this site:

```
https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6462
```

Also I added a few more steps and solutions that I needed to do to make it work.

I hope this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had to build and install [Expat](https://libexpat.github.io/) to get Apache running on windows 10 x64 with the instructions above.  I build on [Windows Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) using the x64 Native Command Prompt. (I installed all the VC and C++ modules - not sure which ones were specifically required.) Also i used the latest version of all of the software listed above so the install commands had to be adjusted accordingly.  Trial by fire!  Good luck.

Comment: Here is a link to a very helpful [discussion](https://asf.ui-eu-01.ponee.io/thread.html/7857e6aefc69c7896797e10828fd420d0acec147b011d899fe2e0fc6@%3Cdev.apr.apache.org%3E) regarding the recent incompatibility with expat

Comment: It seems like [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15) might be a more minimal command line installation

Comment: Am glad that my answer was helpful to you :)

Comment: Followed your link to [apachelounge.com](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6462) to  [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org/wagnersolutions/apache-2.4-build-windows )  where fwagner created a automatic DL powershell script. Had to add expat to the source to get it to build.  Correct environmental variable for PATH LIBS LIBPATH and INCLUDE so the tools and sources can find all their dependencies was the trickiest part.   A few more tweaks and I should have a one click powershell down long.